# ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal dentro de este método?

Tags: vb.net

Buen día, estoy practicando el lenguaje de basic.net, en un ejercicio eh añadido un bucle for  dentro de un método sub llamado HabilitarCajas, la función de esta misma es recorrer todos los controles que contiene el formulario y con una sentencia if compruebo si el control que está actualmente seleccionado por el índice es de tipo TextBox entonces lo habilitara o deshabilitará según el valor booleano que le pase por parámetro; no sé si estoy haciendo algo demás o algo me falta pero no  funciona por alguna razón, él código es así:

```
Sub HabilitarCajas(ByVal sn as Boolean)
  Dim x as Integer
  For x = 0 To Controls.count - 1
    If TypeOf Controls(x) Is Textbox Then
      Controls(x).Enabled = sn
    end If
  Next
End Sub

private sub form1_load(byval sender as system.object, byval e as eventargs) handles mybase.load
HabilitarCajas(false)
end sub
```

Al ejecutar las cajas de texto deberían estar deshabilitadas.

[image: No funciona]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo parece totalmente correcto. Debugueaste a ver si entra y efectivamente los deshabilita?

Comment: Ehhh, no sé muy bien como funciona el debug pero al compilar si me ejecuta la aplicación pero no deshabilita las cajas de texto

Comment: Aprende a debuguear... el ultra super importante y te salvara de todos estos problemas.. pone un punto de interrupcion y fijate que pasa.

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo, me aparecieron dos cuadros uno dice automático y el otro dice pila de llamadas

Comment: por favor, sigue un tutorial o algun video sobre como hacer debug. Tu codigo deberia funcionar, si no esta funcionando, es por otro motivo...

Comment: Sí, eso estoy haciendo bro, muchas gracias por la recomendación :).

Comment: Ya lo solucioné bro

Comment: Al momento de hacer el punto de interrupción me mostraba que la variable contador x estaba contando hasta el número 4 que serían 5 elementos en otras palabras no estaba pasando por las cajas de texto por alguna razón, entonces decidí llamar el control groupbox para que cuente y verifique solo las cajas de texto que se encuentren dentro de ese control, y ahora sí los cuenta y los deshabilita según el booleano que le pase como parámetro

Comment: La coleccion Controls, tiene controles que agrupan a otros controles.. vos estabas solo contando los controles padres, sin entrar en los controles hijos... En tu dibujo, eso no se ve...

Comment: Gracias por tu consejo y tu ayuda, :).

Answer (score 0):

> el índice es de tipo TextBox entonces lo habilitara o deshabilitará según el valor booleano que le pase por parámetro

Un problema que veo aquí es que estás mandando a llamar el metodo *HabilitarCajas* cuando el formulario inicia, y siempre se le manda un false. (Contrario a lo que dices en la pregunta, que sería variable, pero no sé si ese es tu objetivo final o lo hiciste para probar tu codigo). Pero dejando de lado este punto, esta es la solución para que el codigo deshabilite tus textbox:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    HabilitarCajas(False)
End Sub

Sub HabilitarCajas(ByVal sn As Boolean)
    Dim cControl As Control
    For Each cControl In Me.Controls
        If (TypeOf cControl Is TextBox) Then
            cControl.Enabled = sn
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Ya solo manda a llamar el metodo donde necesites
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Referencia usada: [Loop through textboxes](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c61c52db-3edc-4bf7-8e6c-b2fb90a2e2c5/loop-through-textboxes-ie-textbox1text-textbox2text?forum=vblanguage#:%7E:text=Just%20add%20the%20controls%20you%20want%20to%20an,a%20For%20or%20For%20Each%20loop%20to%20iterate.)

Comment: Acabo de probar el código y sigue dando el mismo resultado.

Comment: @JCardenas Al ver el comentario de gbianchi me di cuenta que no había probado tu codigo original; lo hice y funciona al igual que el que te puse de respuesta, debe ser otro problema porque a mi me funciona correctamente; deberías poner breakpoints en el codigo para ver que problema te genera o si está ejecutandose bien

Comment: El Objetivo del código es que al mandar por parámetro false al método, este deshabilitará las cajas de texto, en mi caso mando el parámetro al iniciar la aplicación.

Comment: Estoy probando el punto de interrupción (es la primera vez que hago esto, no sé muy bien como se usa)

Comment: @JCardenas Solo presta atencion a como se comportan los controles y las variables cuando se va ejecutando linea por linea el codigo, lo primero que deberías ver directamente es si realmente se está ejecutando ese codigo, al poner un punto de interrupcion en, por ejemplo, la linea de IF, deberia detenerse, indicando que llegó a ese punto del codigo.

Comment: Bro en tu ejemplo en vez de poner directamente "false" pon el parámetro y envíale mediante form_load false

Comment: @JCardenas no estoy poniendo directamente false a los controles, lo manejé por medio del form_load igual que tú, solo que no lo añadí en la respuesta, igual ahí lo edité

Comment: Si te entiendo, me refiero a que en tu condición dentro del bucle for pusiste directamente "false" en vez del parámetro.

Comment: @JCardenas Oh tienes razón, una disculpa

Comment: No te preocupes bro.

Comment: Estoy viendo un tutorial de cómo usar los puntos de interrupción

Comment: Ya lo solucioné bro

Comment: @JCardenas Perfecto, si puedes añadir el codigo o lo que resolvió tu duda estaría bien para futuros visitantes a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de hacer el punto de interrupción me mostraba que la variable contador x estaba contando hasta el número 4 que serían 5 elementos en otras palabras no estaba pasando por las cajas de texto por alguna razón, entonces decidí llamar el control groupbox para que cuente y verifique solo las cajas de texto que se encuentren dentro de ese control, y ahora sí los cuenta y los deshabilita según el booleano que le pase como parámetro:

```
Sub HabilitarCajas(byval sn as boolean)
 dim x as integer
   for x = 0 to GroupBox.Controls.Count - 1
      if typeof GroupBox.Controls(x) is TextBox Then
         GroupBox.Controls(x).Enabled = sn
      end if
   next
End Sub



Private Sub form1_load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        HabilitarCajas(False)
End Sub
```

[image: :))]